# Visual bug with tk.Radiobuttons

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I made a couple of `Radiobutton`s, but for some reason, they make this strange visual bug. (Apologies for video being cropped.)

[image]
Before any `RadioButton`s are selected, they do this. However, it goes back to normal after I do select any.
This doesn't affect functionality of `Radiobutton`s, but is very frustrating to see.

Code:

```
# self.topbar_TOP is a tk.Frame
var = tk.IntVar()
var.set(0)
file_radiobtn = tk.Radiobutton(master=self.topbar_TOP, variable=var, value=0, text="File")
file_radiobtn.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=0.15, relheight=1)
insert_radiobtn = tk.Radiobutton(master=self.topbar_TOP, variable=var, value=1, text="Insert")
insert_radiobtn.place(relx=0.15, rely=0, relwidth=0.15, relheight=1)
present_radiobtn = tk.Radiobutton(master=self.topbar_TOP, variable=var, value=2, text="Presentation")
present_radiobtn.place(relx=0.3, rely=0, relwidth=0.15, relheight=1)
```

Comment: is `var` defined inside a function?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes. Both ```var``` and the ```Radiobutton```s.

Comment: Then that's almost certainly the problem. Make `var` global and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks, it helped. Can you duplicate it in an answer so I can mark the question as solved?